# Triggers available in Docusign on document completion

Tags: docusignapi

I have a web application integrated with DocuSign API, to pass in recipient details to a DocuSign template and initiate signing process. The template has tags for each recipient to enter relevant information and sign.

Once the document is completed/signed by all recipients, the information available in the document needs to be passed on to another web application bound to a DB. What are the options available in DocuSign to trigger document data(e.g. recipient1 signed date) transferred to a DB/other systems on document completion? Any advice on this is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to provide more specific information but generally, you can use DocuSign Connect and configure your API source to integrate the data. After that, you will be able to use webhooks (or Connect) to send tabs data and signing statuses to your 'other systems'.

Once you get your Connect figured out, you can then have GET request using this

> {{baseUrl}}/envelopes/{{envelopeId}}/recipients?include_tabs=true

and then have a wrapper class to export desired tabs (ex. Date Signed or other Text Tabs)
OR you can configure a webhook to sync your data between DocuSign and other systems: 
[Code Example: Using a Webhook to Track Envelope Status](https://developers.docusign.com/esign-rest-api/code-examples/webhook-status)